# Want to transport a SQL procedure into Salesforce

Tags: integration

I am completely new to Salesforce. I have a procedure (below) that takes data from 2 tables, then does some calculations and then inputs to a third table.

Can anybody help me with the basics of this?

1. Where do I write the code.
2. Do I need declare variables, if not how do I call the values.
3. Can I do the calcs as below then an insert?
4. Do I loop as before?
   5 How do I pass values into the place where I write the code?

DECLARE @AnnSalary as float, @AnnSalaryYTD as float
DECLARE @MonthlyAdj as float;
DECLARE @Expenses as float;
DECLARE @TaxFreeInd as varchar(10);
DECLARE @EmpCountry as varchar(10);
DECLARE @TaxFree as float;
DECLARE @numb as int;
DECLARE @maxemp as int;
DECLARE @PAYEBAND1  as float, @PAYEBAND2 as float, @PAYEBAND3 as float;
DECLARE @PAYERATE1  as float, @PAYERATE2 as float, @PAYERATE3 as float;
DECLARE @NIBAND_LEL  as float, @NIBAND_PT as float, @NIBAND_UEL as float;
DECLARE @NIRATE_LEL  as float, @NIRATE_PT as float, @NIRATE_UEL as float, @NIRATE_UPPER as float;
DECLARE @FEDBAND1  as float, @FEDBAND2 as float, @FEDBAND3 as float, @FEDBAND4  as float, @FEDBAND5 as float, @FEDBAND6 as float, @FEDBAND7 as float;
DECLARE @FEDRATE1  as float, @FEDRATE2 as float, @FEDRATE3 as float, @FEDRATE4  as float, @FEDRATE5 as float, @FEDRATE6 as float, @FEDRATE7 as float;
DECLARE @PAYE as float, @PAYEYTD as float;
DECLARE @NI as float, @NIYTD as float;
DECLARE @FED as float, @FEDYTD as float;
DECLARE @State as float, @StateYTD as float;
DECLARE @NetPay as float;

```
Set @maxemp = (select max(EmployeeID) from dbo.Employees);
Set @numb = 1;

WHILE @numb < @maxemp+1
BEGIN
    --Import Personal Salary Data
    Set @AnnSalary = (select Annual_Salary from tax.SalaryDetails where EmployeeID = @numb)/12;
    Set @MonthlyAdj = (select MonthlyAdjustment from tax.SalaryDetails where EmployeeID = @numb);
    Set @Expenses = (select Expenses from tax.SalaryDetails where EmployeeID = @numb);
    Set @TaxFree = (select TaxFree from tax.SalaryDetails where EmployeeID = @numb)*@TaxMonth/12;
    Set @EmpCountry = (select Country from dbo.Employees where EmployeeID = @numb)

    --Import YTD Salary
    Set @AnnSalaryYTD = (select sum(GrossPay) from tax.HistSalaryPayments where EmployeeID = @numb)
    Set @AnnSalaryYTD = CASE
    WHEN @AnnSalaryYTD is NULL then 0
    else @AnnSalaryYTD end;
    Set @NIYTD = (select sum(NI) from tax.HistSalaryPayments where EmployeeID = @numb)
    Set @NIYTD = CASE
    WHEN @NIYTD is NULL then 0
    else @NIYTD end;
    Set @PAYEYTD = (select sum(PAYE) from tax.HistSalaryPayments where EmployeeID = @numb)
    Set @PAYEYTD = CASE
    WHEN @PAYEYTD is NULL then 0
    else @PAYEYTD end;
    Set @FEDYTD = (select sum(FED) from tax.HistSalaryPayments where EmployeeID = @numb)
    Set @FEDYTD = CASE
    WHEN @FEDYTD is NULL then 0
    else @FEDYTD end;
    Set @StateYTD = (select sum(StateTax) from tax.HistSalaryPayments where EmployeeID = @numb)
    Set @StateYTD = CASE
    WHEN @StateYTD is NULL then 0
    else @StateYTD end;

    ---Calculate PAYE - these are PAYE total for the year
    Set @PAYEBAND1 = (select Limit from tax.TaxRates where TaxType = 'PAYE' and Band = 1) * @TaxMonth / 12;
    Set @PAYEBAND2 = (select Limit from tax.TaxRates where TaxType = 'PAYE' and Band = 2) * @TaxMonth / 12;
    Set @PAYEBAND3 = (select Limit from tax.TaxRates where TaxType = 'PAYE' and Band = 3) * @TaxMonth / 12;

    Set @PAYERATE1 = (select Rate from tax.TaxRates where TaxType = 'PAYE' and Band = 1);
    Set @PAYERATE2 = (select Rate from tax.TaxRates where TaxType = 'PAYE' and Band = 2);
    Set @PAYERATE3 = (select Rate from tax.TaxRates where TaxType = 'PAYE' and Band = 3);

    Set @AnnSalary = @AnnSalary + @AnnSalaryYTD + @MonthlyAdj
        -----Get Tax Free Allowance
        Set @TaxFreeInd = (select TaxClass from tax.SalaryDetails where EmployeeID = @numb)
        Set @TaxFree = 
        CASE
            when @TaxFreeInd = 'S' then ((select SingleAllowance from tax.TaxRates where TaxType = 'PAYE' and Band = 1) * @TaxMonth / 12)
            when @TaxFreeInd = 'Mmin' then ((select MinExtraMarriedAllowance from tax.TaxRates where TaxType = 'PAYE' and Band = 1) * @TaxMonth / 12)
            when @TaxFreeInd = 'Mmax' then ((select MaxExtraMarriedAllowance from tax.TaxRates where TaxType = 'PAYE' and Band = 1) * @TaxMonth / 12)
            when @TaxFreeInd = 'A' then ((select TaxFree from tax.SalaryDetails where EmployeeID = @numb) * @TaxMonth / 12) end;


        Set @PAYE = CASE
        WHEN @EmpCountry = 'USA'
            THEN 0
        WHEN @AnnSalary <  @PAYEBAND1
            THEN (@AnnSalary - @TaxFree) * @PAYEBAND1
        WHEN @AnnSalary <  @PAYEBAND2
            THEN ((@PAYEBAND1 - @TaxFree) * @PAYERATE1) + ((@AnnSalary - @PAYEBAND1) * @PAYERATE2)
            ELSE ((@PAYEBAND1 - @TaxFree) * @PAYERATE1) + ((@PAYEBAND2 - @PAYEBAND1) * @PAYERATE2) + ((@AnnSalary - @PAYEBAND2) * @PAYERATE3) end;

    ----Calculate NI
    Set @NIBAND_LEL = (select Limit from tax.TaxRates where Band = 'LEL') * @TaxMonth / 12
    Set @NIBAND_PT = (select Limit from tax.TaxRates where Band = 'LEL-PT') * @TaxMonth / 12 
    Set @NIBAND_UEL = (select Limit from tax.TaxRates where Band = 'PT-UEL') * @TaxMonth / 12

    Set @NIRATE_LEL = (select Rate from tax.TaxRates where Band = 'LEL')
    Set @NIRATE_PT = (select Rate from tax.TaxRates where Band = 'LEL-PT')
    Set @NIRATE_UEL = (select Rate from tax.TaxRates where Band = 'PT-UEL')
    Set @NIRATE_UPPER = (select Rate from tax.TaxRates where Band = 'UEL')

        Set @NI = CASE
        WHEN @EmpCountry = 'USA'
            THEN 0
        WHEN @AnnSalary <  @NIBAND_LEL
            THEN @AnnSalary * @NIRATE_LEL
        WHEN @AnnSalary <  @NIBAND_PT
            THEN (@NIRATE_LEL * @NIRATE_LEL) + ((@AnnSalary - @NIRATE_LEL) * @NIRATE_PT)
        WHEN @AnnSalary <  @NIBAND_UEL
            THEN (@NIRATE_LEL * @NIRATE_LEL) + ((@NIBAND_PT - @NIBAND_LEL) * @NIRATE_PT) + ((@AnnSalary - @NIBAND_PT) * @NIRATE_UEL)
            ELSE (@NIRATE_LEL * @NIRATE_LEL) + ((@NIBAND_PT - @NIBAND_LEL) * @NIRATE_PT) + ((@NIBAND_UEL - @NIBAND_PT) * @NIRATE_UEL) + ((@AnnSalary -@NIBAND_UEL) * @NIRATE_UPPER)  end;

    -----Calculate US Federal Tax
    Set @FEDBAND1 = (select Limit from tax.TaxRates where TaxType = 'FED' and Band = 1) * @TaxMonth / 12;
    Set @FEDBAND2 = (select Limit from tax.TaxRates where TaxType = 'FED' and Band = 2) * @TaxMonth / 12;
    Set @FEDBAND3 = (select Limit from tax.TaxRates where TaxType = 'FED' and Band = 3) * @TaxMonth / 12;
    Set @FEDBAND4 = (select Limit from tax.TaxRates where TaxType = 'FED' and Band = 4) * @TaxMonth / 12;
    Set @FEDBAND5 = (select Limit from tax.TaxRates where TaxType = 'FED' and Band = 5) * @TaxMonth / 12;
    Set @FEDBAND6 = (select Limit from tax.TaxRates where TaxType = 'FED' and Band = 6) * @TaxMonth / 12;
    Set @FEDBAND7 = (select Limit from tax.TaxRates where TaxType = 'FED' and Band = 7) * @TaxMonth / 12;

    Set @FEDRATE1 = (select Rate from tax.TaxRates where TaxType = 'FED' and Band = 1)
    Set @FEDRATE2 = (select Rate from tax.TaxRates where TaxType = 'FED' and Band = 2)
    Set @FEDRATE3 = (select Rate from tax.TaxRates where TaxType = 'FED' and Band = 3)
    Set @FEDRATE4 = (select Rate from tax.TaxRates where TaxType = 'FED' and Band = 4)
    Set @FEDRATE5 = (select Rate from tax.TaxRates where TaxType = 'FED' and Band = 5)
    Set @FEDRATE6 = (select Rate from tax.TaxRates where TaxType = 'FED' and Band = 6)
    Set @FEDRATE7 = (select Rate from tax.TaxRates where TaxType = 'FED' and Band = 7)

        Set @FED = CASE
        WHEN @EmpCountry = 'UK'
            THEN 0
        WHEN @AnnSalary <  @FEDBAND1
            THEN @AnnSalary * @FEDRATE1
        WHEN @AnnSalary <  @FEDBAND2
            THEN (@FEDBAND1 * @FEDRATE1) + ((@AnnSalary - @FEDBAND1) * @FEDRATE2)
        WHEN @AnnSalary <  @FEDBAND3
            THEN (@FEDBAND1 * @FEDRATE1) + ((@FEDBAND2 - @FEDBAND1) * @FEDRATE2) + ((@AnnSalary - @FEDBAND2) * @FEDRATE3)
        WHEN @AnnSalary <  @FEDBAND4
            THEN (@FEDBAND1 * @FEDRATE1) + ((@FEDBAND2 - @FEDBAND1) * @FEDRATE2) + ((@FEDBAND3 - @FEDBAND2) * @FEDRATE3) + ((@AnnSalary - @FEDBAND3) * @FEDRATE4)
        WHEN @AnnSalary <  @FEDBAND5
            THEN (@FEDBAND1 * @FEDRATE1) + ((@FEDBAND2 - @FEDBAND1) * @FEDRATE2) + ((@FEDBAND3 - @FEDBAND2) * @FEDRATE3) + ((@FEDBAND4 - @FEDBAND3) * @FEDRATE4) + ((@AnnSalary - @FEDBAND4) * @FEDRATE5)
        WHEN @AnnSalary <  @FEDBAND6
            THEN (@FEDBAND1 * @FEDRATE1) + ((@FEDBAND2 - @FEDBAND1) * @FEDRATE2) + ((@FEDBAND3 - @FEDBAND2) * @FEDRATE3) + ((@FEDBAND4 - @FEDBAND3) * @FEDRATE4) + ((@FEDBAND5 - @FEDBAND4) * @FEDRATE5) + ((@AnnSalary - @FEDBAND5) * @FEDRATE6)
        ELSE (@FEDBAND1 * @FEDRATE1) + ((@FEDBAND2 - @FEDBAND1) * @FEDRATE2) + ((@FEDBAND3 - @FEDBAND2) * @FEDRATE3) + ((@FEDBAND4 - @FEDBAND3) * @FEDRATE4) + ((@FEDBAND5 - @FEDBAND4) * @FEDRATE5) + ((@FEDBAND6 - @FEDBAND5) * @FEDRATE6) + ((@AnnSalary - @FEDBAND6) * @FEDRATE7) END;

    Set @NetPay = (@AnnSalary-@AnnSalaryYTD) - (@PAYE-@PAYEYTD) - (@NI-@NIYTD) - (@FED-@FEDYTD)

    INSERT into tax.HistSalaryPayments
    VALUES (@numb, @TaxYear, @TaxMonth, @AnnSalary-@AnnSalaryYTD, @PAYE-@PAYEYTD, @NI-@NIYTD, @FED-@FEDYTD, 0, @NetPay, @Expenses)

    --Set @NetPay = @AnnSalary - @PAYE - @NI - @FED

    --INSERT into tax.HistSalaryPayments
    --VALUES (@numb, @TaxYear, @TaxMonth, @AnnSalary, @PAYE, @NI, @FED, 0, @NetPay, @Expenses)

SET @numb = @numb + 1;
END
```

Answer (score 4):

Honestly, this is too big of a problem to define here. You need to learn how to do the basics in salesforce, and then a lot of this will begin to make sense.

Start by doing some courses in [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/). This will get you familiar with the tool. It sounds like you would need to then set up a couple of objects to house the data you are working with.

This level of support would probably require some support from another person. You could hire a consultant if you want or you could reach out to see if there are any upcoming admins that want exposure/experience and would be willing to work for less than a developer.

There is a lot to salesforce, sorry. But you can find lots of people willing to help and point in the right direction.